# .htaccess virtual subdomain contains root folder

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

Alright, so I have done endless Googling, searching through the "Questions that may already have your answer" of StackOverflow ... I cannot seem to find an answer for this. I would greatly appreciate any help my fair community could provide.

I purchased a wildcard SSL for my design site [planttheidea.com](https://www.planttheidea.com). I set up a variety of subdomains, both for "psuedo-CDN" purposes (css, js, etc), but also for development and admin stuff. Because I have shared hosting can't cannot modify `httpd.conf`, the only way I could get multiple subdomains working with an SSL cert for one IP is this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.planttheidea\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dev/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*) /dev/$1
```

This works incredibly well, and as long as you create it for each subdomain you're golden. There is one major flaw, however: if you do not add a closing `/`, it re-adds the subfolder into the URL. Example:

- [dev.planttheidea.com/planttheidea/](https://dev.planttheidea.com/planttheidea/)

Redirects appropriately, the real structure of planttheidea.com/dev/ gets rewritten to dev.planttheidea.com/.

- [dev.planttheidea.com/planttheidea](https://dev.planttheidea.com/planttheidea)

Redirects with the subfolder re-added ... dev.planttheidea.com/**dev**/planttheidea. The only difference is that finishing `/` to denote the folder closure.

I know that this is a ridiculously small problem, but I must believe there is some ubergenius out there that wrap up this last little thing that is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.planttheidea\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^dev/ /dev%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: 500 with the `/`, 404 without it.

Comment: Can you check Apache error.log and tell me what the error is for 500

Comment: unfortunately not ... im on shared hosting, i cannot access `/var/log`.

Comment: nope, same result. i do like the brevity of it though. :) worth an upvote id say, plus appreciate the help. im at my wits end!